# Fetch data from nodejs to a reactjs component

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I built my react app.
I have 2 main folders. The first folder contains my react-app and the second contains my nodejs server. In the first file i've created 2 pages and i want to fetch data from nodejs server to one of my page from react app.

```
//Here is my nodejs file 
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST request to the homepage');
});

app.listen(4000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 4000!');
});
```

```
//Here is my react page where i want to fetch data from nodejs
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const Home = () => {

  useEffect(async function () {
      const url = 'http://localhost:4000/';
      const response =  await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data)
    });

  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      <p>{data}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

In the future i want to get data also from a nosql database using nodejs, but now I can't pass data from one node js file into reactjs file. How to do this?

Comment: This example isn't clear. Where is the data you want to give to the app? Is it just the string `"POST request to the homepage"`? How is the React page being served in the first place? As written, `fetch` is making a GET request but there's no route for a GET request. Please add more details to your example and show the expected result. Thank you.

Comment: Most probably your problem is that you are making a `get` request and only have a listener for `post` requests

Comment: @ggorlen, for the moment i want to now how to get `The string "POST request to the homepage"`, or anything else what could be passed in `send` method. So, how to get this string? How to change the `fetch()` for getting what i want?

Comment: OK, that's fine. As mentioned above, the route is a POST request but you're making a GET request, so either change the route to `get` instead of `post` or make a POST request using `fetch(url, { method: 'POST' });`.